# WPF Measuring Text Width Incorrectly with TextFormattingMode="Display" and Hyphens

Tags: wpf, text, formatting, gdi, textblock

You can see the issue and how to reproduce it here:

[image: Missing Word Issue]

The issue results in words being cut off at the end of the longest line in a block of text. Note the last `TextBlock` is missing the word "animals".

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue? Or any information about it? I need to essentially keep the rendering and layout behaviour of the second `TextBlock` - but just have all words present.

XAML reproduction code:

```
<Window x:Class="TextWeirdness.Application.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>

        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=ATextBox}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=ASlider}"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Slider Name="ASlider" Minimum="1" Maximum="30" Value="12" />
        <TextBox Name="ATextBox" Text="I love mules - best of all the animals" AcceptsReturn="True"/>

        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

More information:

- Issue only happens when hyphens (minus symbols only though) are present in the text.
- Only happens when font size is within a specific recurring range (I don't know what that is though).
- Only happens with certain fonts.

  - Arial
  - Buxton Sketch
  - Calibri
  - Calibri Light
  - Cambria
  - Cambria Math
  - Constantia
  - Corbel
  - DokChampa
  - Euphemia
  - Global Monospace
  - Global Sans Serif
  - Global Serif
  - Mongolian Baiti
  - Nyala
  - Palatino Linotype
  - Times New Roman

Comment: does it still happen if you remove `<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>` ?

Comment: The issue does go away when `HorizontalAlignment` is `Stretch`, but I would like to keep that behaviour, if possible.

Comment: for what it's worth, I'm seeing this with the space character -- the width of that character is showing up differently in Display vs. Ideal mode

Answer (score 1):

If you could remove

```
<Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
```

then that would work as workaround...

This is a bug and you should report it via Microsoft Connect site, but don't hold your breath on getting it fixed any time soon. In fact it will probably never get fixed.

My experience has shown that in the last few years, Microsoft takes more than 6 months to respond (if ever), most bugs will be classified as By Design or if you read between the lines "Microsoft has better things to do than do fix bugs". My estimate would be <5% chance of this getting fixed by .NET 5.0

Comment: I did submit it, and they answered pretty much as you said. [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789367/wpf-measuring-text-width-incorrectly-with-textformattingmode-display-and-hyphens).

As for your answer, I really wanted to keep the style of the textblock, but that does indeed work around the issue.

Comment: @Locdarb -  well then there is nothing else to do, except live with this bug. (Unless you want to start rallying people to your cause, to get enough votes to make Microsoft see that this is in fact impacting "the highest number of WPF developers" or at least high enough to make Microsoft care...)

Answer (score 1):

We are experiencing the same issue. Our clients are able to customize the font family and size and some of them reported missing words.

The workaround we chose is to replace the default hyphen/minus by the &#8208; unicode character. This seems correct in the sense of punctuation but is somewhat cumbersome anyway. That's why we're thinking about checking and updating all resx-files on the build server automatically.